# How do I create a class with the same name as a built-in one without overshadowing it in Raku?

Tags: raku

This is quite silly and I know the obvious thing to do is simply naming the class differently but I'm still curious. In the class `ColumnType::Date`, I'd like `typecast` to return a Raku's [`Date`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Date) object, and not a `ColumnType::Date` one:

```
module ColumnType {
    class Date {
        method typecast(Blob:D $value) {
            my $date = $value.decode('ascii').trim;
            my ($year, $month, $day) = $date.split('/');
            return try Date.new: :$year, :$month, :$day;
        }
    }
}

my $blob = "1980/01/01".encode('ascii');
say ColumnType::Date.new.typecast($blob);
```

In other words, is it possible to reference Raku's `Date` as a fully-qualified name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  By prefixing `CORE::`.

```
$ raku -e 'say CORE::Date =:= Date'
True
```

EDIT:

More generally, you can access something that is lexically available after lexically overriding it, by using `my constant`.  In your example, you could also have done:

```
module ColumnType {
    my constant OriginalDate = Date;
    class Date {
        method typecast(Blob:D $value) {
            my $date = $value.decode('ascii').trim;
            my ($year, $month, $day) = $date.split('/');
            return try OriginalDate.new: :$year, :$month, :$day;
        }
    }
}
```

This will "save" the visibility of the class `Date` inside the module as `OriginalDate`, which you can then use to call `.new` on.

Comment: does constant bind like :=, then?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: @librasteve "does constant bind like `:=`, then?" Ah, ambiguities. In the sense you presumably meant, and Liz intuited, yes: `constant foo = bar` and `constant foo := bar` mean exactly the same thing. But for readers who may think otherwise, unlike the way `:=` works with `my` variables, `constant` is a one time deal -- you can't write `foo := baz` to change the binding -- and the binding is done at *compile time*, not *run-time*.